# Opening a Chrome tab in a new window, the new window is transparent and also flickers

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome

When opening a Chrome tab in a new window, the new window becomes transparent and nothing is visible, as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image: Screenshot showing the issue]

I have a GTX 1050 Ti (tried with driver version 470 and latest driver version 495 ).

I tried reinstalling Chrome and also tried previous versions of it, but still it is was not working properly and the issue remained.

See the video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nwUhJOL4UQfd2_anQU9cvXKngZinp_Bb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please include info on your system and graphics card, and on the Ubuntu version where the problem occurs.

Comment: @vanadium see the video in link

Comment: I have this problem too. It happens even if I switch to a new workspace and open chrome in the new workspace, it's transparent and I only see a ghost outline.

Answer (score 0):

I recently hit same issue, after I experimented with NVidia driver settings.
Disabling FXAA in "X Screen 0 → Antialiasing settings" helped me with this issue.